# SSRS Column Subtraction Conditions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, excel-formula, calculated-columns

I'm working on an SSRS report and I'd like to know how to do the following. The following are my columns:

```
coins total (exc. July and Aug)   |  disposable coins  |   coins redeemed  |   new disposable coins total  |   updated coins total
```

What I need to do is add *new disposable coins total* to *coins total (exc. July and Aug)* if and only if *new disposable coin total* is < 0 (a negative value). I know this sounds like a very roundabout way of accomplishing what I'd like to do, but it's the way it's made sense to me after mulling it over for a few hours. So is there an iif style formula I can write in an SSRS column expression field to get that new total?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=iif(new disposable coin total  < 0, 
new disposable coins total + coins total (exc. July and Aug), 0)
```

You can drag the columns into the expression builder